# How to launch Charles Proxy using shell script?

Tags: java

I am using charles proxy to collect http logs in my automation test framework, I want to launch the charles from terminal after initializing the automation framework.
Is there any way to launch charles proxy and  stop without manually launching the same.

I am using mac.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy, since I am using mac book, I have used

```
open -a Charles
```

This has launched the charles proxy for me.

In Java:

```
try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -a Charles");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For MAC users, Navigate to terminal and enter:

```
export CHARLES_HOME=/Applications/Charles.app/Contents/MacOS
export PATH=$PATH:$CHARLES_HOME
```

Then in order to launch the Charles in HEADLESS Mode:

```
Charles -headless
```